# Resources for testing language level

Tags: resource, proficiency-test

How can I test my german level and see if I am actually improving?
Are there any "reliable" online test that can be used?
Could the "readability test" be a good idea?

Comment: What's the "readability test"?

Comment: From Wikipedia: Readability is the ease in which text can be read and understood. And the readability test: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability_test

Comment: This isn't really a testing resource but I think this scale poses some good questions to ask when self-assessing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILR_scale

Answer (score 1):

[Duolingo](http://duolingo.com) also offers the ability to take a timed test if you want.  Otherwise it provides one test after another in various forms: translations, transcription (typing what you hear), and multiple choice.  If you have a mic, you can even get some questions that let you practice speaking sentences.  The tests get harder as you progress.  You can go back and review, too.

I recommend it.

Comment: I agree, Duolingo's timed tests are probably what you're looking for. They don't provide feedback on what you did wrong, but you can take them regularly and see if your score improves. Other than that, you can test individual skills in the German course.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this test](http://www.goethe.de/cgi-bin/einstufungstest/einstufungstest.pl) from the german "Goethe-Institute" is helpful. It seems to focus on grammatical details.
I would recommend reading and listening to german texts (written/spoken by natives).

Comment: I Tried it and it's not bad, but it doesn't give enough information. For example it doesn't show which question I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The tests on [Duolingo.com](https://www.duolingo.com/) are very good because with use they give you a very good assessment of your current level. You can take shortcut tests to 'pass' the easier level tests to quickly get to the relevant tests for your level.